# The import java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved

Tags: java, ubuntu-16.04

i'm using Ubuntu 16, and started tutorial on java, and now i have one issue with my code, the method "Arrays.toString()", like all path "java.util.Arrays", is not found, and i really do not know, what i need to do.

This is my code:

```
package introtocs.arrayalgorithms;

import java.util.Arrays; // First issue here

public class FillingAndDeleting {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Filling Arrays
        int[] oneThroughTen = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < oneThroughTen.length; i++) {
            oneThroughTen[i] = i + 1;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(oneThroughTen)); // Second here
        }

    }

}
```

Please help, i cant continue.

Comment: Do you have path environment variable properly configured?

Comment: What is saying java.util.Arrays is not found?

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: Please add to you post the full error message

Comment: First Error is "The import java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved"

Comment: Second one: "Arrays cannot be resolved"

Comment: it's console result: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Arrays cannot be resolved

 at introtocs.arrayalgorithms.FillingAndDeleting.main(FillingAndDeleting.java:15)

Comment: Im use Java 8, and this is screen of errors http://imageshack.com/a/img923/3725/Nw2cGs.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is add file to current eclipse project, `"util -> Arrays.java"`,
make package util, and after download file Arrays.java from [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java)

Comment: your link is broken

Answer (score 0):

this code runs normally on my eclipse, i think maybe you didn't build the path, so there is a error to import the Arrays utils.